# When a SIGTSTP signal is encountered by the readline and the user has a callback, will the process be sent background after callback? [NODE JS]

Tags: node.js, readline, child-process

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

rl.on('SIGTSTP', () => {
    console.log(process.pid);
});
```

Will the process be sent to background after the PID is printed?

Answer (score 0):

[As per the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#event-sigtstp):

> If there are no 'SIGTSTP' event listeners registered when the input stream receives a SIGTSTP, the Node.js process will be sent to the background.

The process is sent to background if there are *no* event listeners.

So because you have attached a listener here, it will prevent the process from being sent to the background.

See the comment in the example from the docs:

```js
rl.on('SIGTSTP', () => {
  // This will override SIGTSTP and prevent the program from going to the
  // background.
  console.log('Caught SIGTSTP.');
});
```